# Disable CSS rule on devices with touch screens

Tags: css, touch

I am using this breadcrumb script on my website:

https://mtekk.us/archives/guides/vista-like-breadcrumbs-for-wordpress/

When I mouse over the links a set of sub-menus pop up. This works fine and I have no complaints on my PC. However, you can't properly mouseover on mobile devices, so I'd like to disable the popping up of the sub-menus on mobiles.

Is there a way to detect mobile devices that doesn't rely on pixel screen sizes in media queries? My problem here is not the screen size, but rather the input method. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819886/5730322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new [Level 4 Media Query](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#descdef-media-hover) that could very well become *the* way to do this.

The real magic is `hover: hover`, but here is some info on `pointer: fine` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer):

> The primary input mechanism includes an accurate pointing device.

You could use the query like this:

```css
@media(hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
  .navigation-main ul li:hover>ul {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Here is a [test site](https://hover-pointer-media-query.glitch.me/) where you can test the new @media queries against your device.

Comment: What is the best fallback method for old browsers?

Comment: @posfan12 For older browsers, it looks like JavaScript is the best way to go, though it's imperfect. The **Update 2018** part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript/4819886#4819886) answer is what I'd do for older browser support.